# C# using System.Net.Mail; not working

Tags: c#, email, smtp, system.net.mail

I'm creating an app for windows phones, and I'm trying to create a feedback form using googles smtp. I know the code I'm using is fine but for some reason when I put

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

it displays the following error;

"The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I don't understand why it's doing this as I had to do it a few months back and it worked fine then. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the assembly reference? ...

Comment: @svranken "All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced. Please use the Object Browser to explore the references in the Framework."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no SMTP libraries available on Windows-Phone 8 thats why you are getting this issue because your project is not allowed to reference the assembly.

You will have to use a 3rd party API to interact with SMTP. SendGrid has been mentioned before.

Comment: Ah I see, well that sucks. Thanks anyway will have a look at SendGrid then